# Error Upgrading HDD to SSD

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am having difficuties installing Ubuntu OS in a new SSD upgraded in an old Dell E6530.
the error would always occur when it says "executing curtin install partinioning step" and start installing system.
The error has occurred 5 time as much as repeated trying to install.

Installing method:

LIVE USB 8GB.
UBUNTU 23.0

My Laptop spec.
Dell E6530
CPU: 9th gen
CPU Freq: 3.0GHz
RAM: 8GB
SSD: Fanxiang SSD (512GB) in SATA enclosure

I was using HDD 500GB and dual boot (UBUNTU & Window 11).
Now I got new laptop dedicated for the windows and wish to dedicate the dell to UBUNTU.
I bought and installed 512GB SSD (550mb/s) to improve the dell.
I am not novice installing UBUNTU, for I been using it for more 10years but now all efforts
to install have failed.

I initially suspected the first SSD (Samsung 980MB/s), so I changed to Fanxiang
SSD with lower speed 550MB/s. the problem persisted.

I have tried various image writers (Rufus, win32disk imager and balena Etcher).

I have used GPT and MBR partitioning with no success.

I removed the drive from the internal and used enclose as external drive yet the error
will surface at the same point.

I stepdown to UBUNTU 22.04 LTS yet the issue persisted.

My last suspicion is on DELL E6530 configuration, maybe been an old system, it has speed
compactibility with the SSD speed but I have no mean to verify this suspicion.

So I am asking if anyone know a wokring bypass.[This error i stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi9IZ.jpg)

Comment: Did you verify the ISO?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware & SSD firmware to latest available. My Samsung had an ISO to convert to bootable to update my NVMe drive. Only use gpt and UEFI boot with that new of a system. If using external drive you must partition in advance and include an ESP - efi system partition on external. Or disconnect internal drive so only external seen. I have installed 22.04 Kubuntu which uses the older Ubiquity installer with this bug.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Ubuntu newer than 22.04 use Subquity installer.

Comment: Not verify the SHA, 
I had changed from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 23.0 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. 
I downloaded fresh copies.

Comment: hi Oldfred, 
no, I will have to try it now. I didnt know I will need to update the firmware.

Comment: What model Dell & chip? Google search says E6530 has 3rd Gen Intel chip? Older Dell with 3rd Gen often needed BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode on, but still boot in UEFI mode. How much RAM. If 4GB, may be better with Kubuntu or a lightweight flavor. And if RST in UEFI, you probably have to turn that off. My 11th Gen Intel based Dell just worked iwht Kubuntu 22.04 once I turned Windows bitlocker & fast startup off. But same install to external SSD worked on 2006 laptop.

Comment: The RAM is 8GB. 
I managed to install the OS using the same GPT partitioning, but if you ask me, there is nothing different now from previous attempts make which failed. 
Let me see how trouble free it will run.

Thank you all for your various inputs.